# why can't I set epsilon=1e-4 on Spark KMeans algorithm?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

I want to train a K-means model on Spark by setting `epsilon=1e-4` instead of setting `numIterations`. In spark shell, I input:

```
val model = KMeans.train(trainRDD, numClusters=8, runs=30, initializationMode="k-means||",epsilon=1e-4)
```

but error, the error information as follows:

```
scala> val model = KMeans.train(trainRDD, numClusters=8, runs=30, initializationMode="k-means||",epsilon=1e-4)
<console>:48: error: overloaded method value train with alternatives:
  (data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector],k: Int,maxIterations: Int,runs: Int)org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel <and>
  (data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector],k: Int,maxIterations: Int)org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel <and>
  (data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector],k: Int,maxIterations: Int,runs: Int,initializationMode: String)org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel <and>
  (data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector],k: Int,maxIterations: Int,runs: Int,initializationMode: String,seed: Long)org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeansModel
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector], numClusters: Int, runs: Int, initializationMode: String, epsilon: Double)
       val model = KMeans.train(trainRDD, numClusters=8, runs=30, initializationMode="k-means||",epsilon=1e-4)
                          ^
```

what should I do?

Comment: try the setEpsilon method

Comment: how to do it? @croxy

Comment: @kiseliu How to do what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such `train` method defined.

Use the real *constructor*, and set the parameters as desired.

See the documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.KMeans

And then use `setEpsilon` to set the early termination threshold.